# using ng-click with templating and parameters

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass parameters, and an answer on SO suggested not to use handle bars but it's not working either.. Looking for a concise way.

**Edit** - changed the var name to `data` from `event` to avoid the confusion with (`$event`)

```
<a ng-click="delete(data.id)">Delete</a></td>
```

or

```
<a ng-click="delete({{data.id}})">Delete</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to access the click event? If so its [$event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) not `event`:

```
<a ng-click="delete($event.id)">Delete</a>
```

If you have an other `event` object defined on your scope, the first should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, i still have problem, there was some confusion with the $event, it just happened that my data name was event, so It was working fine, until I had more than one record, I've updated my question

Comment: Your first option should work fine, there must be another issue. If you `<a ng-click="delete(data.id)">{{data.id}}</a></td>` does the id write out there.